# Showing that $x=0$ is a minimum point by using Taylor's expansion

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Find all the triplets $(\alpha ,\beta, \gamma)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, such that the function $$f(x)=e^x +\alpha \arctan(x) + \beta \arctan^2(x) +\gamma \arctan^3(x)$$
>   has a minimum in $x=0$.

**My solution**.
By taking the derivative I obtain $$f'(x)=e^x +\frac{\alpha}{1+x^2} +\frac{2 \beta \arctan(x)}{1+x^2} +\frac{3 \gamma \arctan2(x)}{1+x^2}$$

So the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)=0$.
Expanding the terms I find that every term has a $x$ beyond, except $1+ \alpha$, so the triplets are infinite $(-1, \beta, \gamma)$.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the connection between the title and the question?

Comment: I think that this problem must be solved with Taylor's expansions. If there are other methods, I would like to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $x=0$ up to "some" order and recall the [higher-order derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test).

Up to the first order,
$$f(x)=1+x+\alpha x+O(x^2)=1+(1+\alpha) x+O(x^2)$$
which implies that if there is a minimum at $0$ then $1+\alpha=0$ (otherwise $f$ is strictly monotonic in a neighbourhood of $0$), hence $\alpha=-1$.

Now, with $\alpha=-1$, up to the second order, 
$$f(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+(-1)(x)+\beta(x^2)+O(x^3)=1+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\beta\right) x^2+O(x^3)$$
and if $\frac{1}{2}+\beta> 0$ then $0$ is a minimum point. It is a maximum point when $\frac{1}{2}+\beta<0$.

To check the case when $\frac{1}{2}+\beta=0$, that is $\beta=-\frac{1}{2}$, you should consider the expansion up to the third order:
$$f(x)=1+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\gamma\right) x^3+O(x^4).$$
If there is a minimum at $0$ then $\frac{1}{2}+\gamma=0$ that is $\gamma=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Finally, with $\alpha=-1$, $\beta=\gamma=-\frac{1}{2}$, in order to see if $0$ is a minimum point, check the expansion up to the fourth order.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes. Then I can put every $\beta, \gamma$ I want but $f$ will always have a minimum in $x=0$? (If $\alpha=-1$)

Comment: No. There are more details in my answer now.

Comment: @Besh00 Have you found the triplets?

Comment: Wow, thanks. Since the 4-th order is $f(x)=1+x^4 \left(\frac{1}{24} -\gamma -\frac{2\beta}{3} \right)$, the argument in brackets is positive, so the triplet $(-1,-1/2,-1/2)$ is correct.

Comment: Yes, but you are forgetting the infinite triplets $(-1,\beta,\gamma)$ with $\beta>-1/2$ and $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Also the triplet $(-1, \beta >-\frac{1}{2}, \forall \gamma \in \mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: Yes, I was writing it. Thanks!

Comment: Great! BTW, if you are new here take a few minutes for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

From $$f'(x)=e^x +\frac{\alpha}{1+x^2} +\frac{2 \beta \arctan(x)}{1+x^2} +\frac{3 \gamma \arctan2(x)}{1+x^2}$$
you find $f'(0)=1+\alpha $.

There is no  need for $ \lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)=0$

The other issue is that: how do you know that x=0 is a minimizer just by $f'(0)=0?$.

You need to verify that it is indeed a minimizer by second derivative test.